# How to get the last value in a list/string using Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in writing Python scripts and I need help on the following:

Threads::num,47141,47146,47151,47156,47161,47166,47171,47176

How can I get and display the last value '47176'?

The following is the part of the code I have written:

```
elif sys.argv[1] == "-c":
    b = sys.argv[2]
    with open(b) as f:
        for line in f:
            if 'Threads::num' in line:
                print line.strip(',').split(',')[-1]
                print line
```

The output of this code is that it displays all the values as follows:

```
Threads::num,47141,47146,47151,47156,47161,47166,47171,47176
```

-sid

Comment: Posts on this corner of the SE network are expected to relate to software testing and/or quality assurance in some way. This post fails to meet that criterion.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
threads_string = "Threads::num,47141,47146,47151,47156,47161,47166,47171,47176"
split_threads_string = threads_string.split(',')
print split_threads_string[-1]
```

Comment: I solved it: I gave  print split_threads_string[-2] as there was a newline involved at the end of the line.

Comment: I would suggest trimming it before splitting.  If the answe rabove is correct you should mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

if sys.argv[1] == '-c':
    b = sys.argv[2]

with open(b) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('Threads::num'):
            print line.split(',')[-1].strip()
```

Also I would suggest using optparse instead of sys.argv

Comment: Hi Jason thanks for the reply and I have solved the issue i have used I gave  print split_threads_string[-2] as there was a newline involved at the end of the line.